# uniformly split sequence with constraints

Tags: r, algorithm

I would like (roughly) uniformly split sequence with inclusion/exclusion constraints. I am looking for such function in R (thus, describe in R), but it think it is a good algorithm problem too :)

The following setup describes the problem.

```
## size
n = 5 # length of a sequence
m = 3 # number of groups

## constraints
# inclusion constraints
# same index (for example, first two elements) must be in a same group.
ic = c(1,1,2,3,4)
# exclusion constraints
# same index (for example, last two elements) must not be in a same group.
ec = c(1,2,3,4,4)

## run
g = uniform_split(n, m, ic, ec) # the function I am looking for!

# possible g when m = 3:
g = c(1,1,2,2,3) # most preferred
g = c(1,1,3,2,3) # most preferred
g = c(1,1,1,2,3) # satisfies constraints, but less balanced.

# possible g when m = 2:
g = c(1,1,2,1,2) # most preferred
g = c(1,1,2,2,1) # most preferred
g = c(1,1,1,1,2) # satisfies constraints, less balanced
g = c(1,1,1,2,1) # satisfies constraints, less balanced
```

As shown, the possible sequence may not be just one, or may not even exists. So, the result does not need to be exactly balanced, nor need to give all possible choices. One of roughly uniform result would be enough, if it is possible, for my need. Still, the quality of grouping can be defined by the norm of a vector: `distance = (count_in_group(1), count_in_group(2), ... count_in_group(m)) - (n/m, n/m, ..., n/m)`.

In addition, you may assume the following, to simply (or possibly complicate) the problem.

- m <= n: This eliminates trivial cases.
- inclusion constraints / exclusion constraints are monotonically non-decreasing: This would make that only neighbors have inclusion / exclusion relationships.
- O(n) solution wihth reasonably good result is preferred (not sure whether it is possibly nor best).

Such grouping is used to split data frame and distribute the work into multiple cores. R's `parallel::clusterSplit` function would split the sequence without considering constraints.

n=5,m=3 is chosen for example purpose. In reality, n would be thousands (# of rows of data frame) and m would be few dozens/hundreds (# of cores).

Anyone has a good idea how to write such a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After merging the items that must go together (and adding their weights), this problem is a partition problem with some side constraints about items coexisting in a partition. Since partitioning is NP-hard in general, I would try first a greedy strategy that considers in turn each maximal group of items that cannot coexist and packs them into the least loaded partitions (heaviest to least, second heaviest to second least, etc.). Do the "difficult" groups first (maximum total weight first). If R has a decent priority queue, then this should be plenty fast.

There may be cleverer combinatorial optimization algorithms, but I suspect that they won't be worth it, given the limitations of open-loop scheduling.